# Microsoft Avro serializer is mangling provided schemas

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, avro

I'm trying to write out Avro files, and having some real trouble with the serialization.  I'm using [Microsoft.Avro.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Avro.Core/0.1.0), and recently discovered that when I give it a schema containing a `type` with an associated `logicalType`, it will inexplicably extract the inner `type` and use that to replace it!  This means that my `DateTime` declaration of `"type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-micros"}` is now a simple `"type": "long"`, which the recipient is unable to interpret properly.

If it were simply doing this internally to understand what data types it's working with, that would be one thing.  But this mangled schema is *actually being written to the output file,* which is completely incorrect behavior.  Does anyone know a way to fix or work around this?

(And yes, the library hasn't been updated in 5 years and is probably completely unsupported.  But it was the only .NET Avro serializer I could find that fulfills one crucial requirement: allowing me to work with arbitrary types not known at compile-time.  Everything else seems to want to only use generic serializers of type `T`, but my use case can't provide that `T`.  So I can't abandon this library for something better unless there actually is something better that I can use.  But if there is, I'd be open to it.)

Comment: Try using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro
I think the Microsoft package was abandoned because this one is much better

Comment: @BronDavies Please read my last paragraph.  Looking at the documentation for this package, it doesn't appear that there's any way to write out data without a type `T` whose type is known at compile-time.  That's a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: Can you add some code that demonstrates the inputs and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fair amount of searching and poking through poorly-documented source code, I found a solution.  Even though the [official Avro library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro) from Apache does require a generic type parameter for all of its readers and writers, if you specify the type as [`GenericRecord`](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/src/apache/main/Generic/GenericRecord.cs), it will let you work with the `GenericRecord` as a runtime-defined structure.  (This is not an arbitrary dynamic type, as the values you assign to its fields still have to match the provided schema.)

Meanwhile, this library's type system has much wider support for Avro's type set than the abandoned Microsoft one does.  It correctly works with Avro's logical types and converts between them and CLR types the way you would expect it should work, with one notable exception: serializing a `DateTime` will convert it from the system's local time to UTC.  (There's probably a way to work around this but I haven't found it yet.)

Just leaving this here in case anyone runs into similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the behavior and put together a small program, that doesn't use generics.

Indeed, from what I can see the DateTime *sub type* is still omitted from the schema, which is really confusing and frustrating, because the receiver needs to know up-front, possible by using the field name ?!, which long fields are of the type DateTime and which not.?!    By default it uses Ticks to parse DateTimes. I looked a bit over the Avro library on github and I saw it uses *runtimeType* for DateTime and DateTimeOffset.

It probably doesn't help you too much, but maybe it helps someone out there with similar problems.

```
[DataContract]
public struct TestMsg
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id;
    [DataMember]
    public double Amount;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime OrderSubmitted;
    public TestMsg(int id, double amount, DateTime orderSubmitted)
    {
        Id = id;
        Amount = amount;
        OrderSubmitted = orderSubmitted;
    }
}


internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line = Environment.NewLine;

        string fileName = "Messages.avro";
        string filePath = null;
        if (Environment.NewLine.Contains("\r"))
        {
            filePath = new DirectoryInfo(".") + @"\" + fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = new DirectoryInfo(".") + @"/" + fileName;
        }

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList
        {
            new TestMsg(1, 189.12, DateTime.Now),
            new TestMsg(2, 345.94, new DateTime(2000, 1, 10, 15, 20, 23, 103))
        };

        var schema = @"
        {
            ""type"" : ""record"",
            ""name"" : ""TestAvro.TestMsg"",
            ""fields"" : [
                {
                    ""name"" : ""Id"",
                    ""type"": ""int""
                },
                {
                    ""name"" : ""Amount"",
                    ""type"":  ""double""
                },
                {
                    ""name"" : ""OrderSubmitted"",
                    ""type"": ""long"",
                    ""runtimeType"": ""DateTime""
                }
            ]
        }";
            
        using (var dataStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var serializer = AvroSerializer.CreateGeneric(schema);
            using (var avroWriter = AvroContainer.CreateGenericWriter(schema, dataStream, Codec.Null))
            {
                
                using (var seqWriter = new SequentialWriter<object>(avroWriter, al.Count))
                {

                    var avroRecords = new List<AvroRecord>();
                    

                    foreach (var item in al)
                    {
                        dynamic record = new AvroRecord(serializer.WriterSchema);
                        record.Id = ((TestMsg)item).Id;
                        record.Amount = ((TestMsg)item).Amount;
                        record.OrderSubmitted = ((TestMsg)item).OrderSubmitted.Ticks;
                        
                        seqWriter.Write(record);
                    }
                }
            }
            dataStream.Dispose();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now reading file.");

        using (var dataStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var avroReader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(schema, dataStream, true, new CodecFactory()))
            {
                using (var seqReader = new SequentialReader<object>(avroReader))
                {

                    foreach (var dynamicItem in seqReader.Objects)
                    {
                        dynamic obj = (dynamic)dynamicItem;
                        
                        Console.WriteLine($" {obj.Id} - {obj.Amount} - {new DateTime(obj.OrderSubmitted).ToString()}");
                    }
                }
            }
            dataStream.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Which Avro library on Github?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/dougmsft/microsoft-avro

Comment: Wow, I was not aware that this was even on Github.  The NuGet page didn't provide a repo link.